# Recast an existing control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to recast an existing control?

For example, if we loop up the control tree until we find a control of the type of `bob` (obviously without any checks for infinite loops here):

```
Control parentCtrl = this.parent;
do
(
   if(parentCtrl.getType == typeof(bob)) { break; }
   else { parentCtrl = parentCtrl.parent; }
) while (true)

// This is the bit...?
bob parentCtrl = (bob)parentCtrl; // <-- will not compile as `parentCtrl` has been defined already
```

I know I can do `((bob)parentCtrl).ctrlSpecificAttribute = "whatever dude...";` however being lazy, I'd like to save a few parentheses and keystrokes.

Is the only solution to have a separate target control?

```
bob targetCtrl = (bob)parentCtrl;
```

Comment: _"Is the only solution to have a separate target control?"_ Yes, because not every `Control` is `Bob`.

Comment: you can already declare parentCtrl as bob if bob extends Control class

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo: Not every control is bob even if every bob is of type control.

Comment: @TimSchmelter what if I were to use `var parentCtrl` and then recast that? Or is there any performance / memory impact of using two object for ultimately the same thing?

Comment: @RemarkLima: `var` is not `dynamic`, so i'm not sure how you want to do that. However, it's definitely better to use a different variable for bob and your controls.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter - Please add that as an answer and I'll mark it correct. I was trying to be efficient with my variables, but I guess it's small change really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is the only solution to have a separate target control?"

Yes, because not every `Control` *is* `Bob`.

> What if I were to use var parentCtrl and then recast that? Or is there
>   any performance / memory impact of using two object for ultimately the
>   same thing?

`var` is not `dynamic`, so i'm not sure how you want to do that. However, it's definitely better to use a different variable for `bob` and your `controls`.